# IPv6 address as the domain portion of an email address

Tags: email, ip, ipv6, email-validation

I'm trying to test a new email validation function I've written, based on [this one.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585), but with some minor adjustments.

From a large set of valid and invalid entries, the function finds just one false negative - an address which has an IPv6 address instead of a domain.

```
user@[IPv6:2001:db8:1ff::a0b:dbd0]
```

The source is this wikipedia page: [Email Addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Valid_email_addresses)

However, `System.Net.IPAddress` fails to parse `IPv6:2001:db8:1ff::a0b:dbd0`, and I can't find any references in the [RFC4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.2) to any prefix of IPv6.

Obviously, `IPv6:2001:db8:1ff::a0b:dbd0` is not a valid IPv6 address, but is it valid in an *email* address? Or is wikipedia wrong?

Should the actual email be `user@[2001:db8:1ff::a0b:dbd0]` Anyone know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right to look at RFC4291 for the IPv6 address format. However, for SMTP (and thus for any other email software handling addresses) you should also look at [Address Literals](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.3) in [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321).

The one you want is probably "IPv6-address-literal".

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for this, the `IPv6:` prefix tag is required.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.3

> For IPv6 and other forms of addressing that might eventually be standardized, the form consists of a standardized "tag" that identifies the address syntax, a colon, and the address itself ...